# How to add or manipulate http header in a webservice call in java

Tags: web-services, soap, http-headers, jax-rpc, custom-headers

There is a requirement to add a new http header key value pair in a soap request. Something like below.

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Pragma: no-cache
 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
 New-Key: Some dynamic value

 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
```

How can I add a new key value pair (New-Key: Some dynamic value) in http header while making a soap request? Value will later get extracted by server from http header. As a requirement new field should neither be added in soap header nor in soap body.

We are using IBM wsdl2java tool, which implements the IBM JAX-RPC specification to generate the Java clients and invoke the SOAP web service calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans at 
 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rwbs_transportheaderproperty.html

```
public class MyApplicationClass {
// Inject an instance of the service's port-type.
@WebServiceRef(EchoService.class)
private EchoPortType port;

// This method will invoke the web service operation and send and receive transport headers.
public void invokeService() {

    // Set up the Map that will contain the request headers.
    Map<String, Object>requestHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    requestHeaders.put(“Cookie”, “ClientAuthenticationToken=FFEEBBCC”);
    requestHeaders.put(“MyHeaderFlag”, new Boolean(true));

    // Set the Map as a property on the RequestContext.
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(com.ibm.websphere.webservices.Constants.REQUEST_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES, requestHeaders);

    // Set up the Map to retrieve transport headers from the response message.
    Map<String, Object>responseHeaders = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    responseHeaders.put(“Set-Cookie”, null);
    responseHeaders.put(“MyHeaderFlag, null);

    // Invoke the web services operation.
    String result = port.echoString(“Hello, world!”);

    // Retrieve the headers from the response.
    String cookieValue = responseHeaders.get(“Set-Cookie”);
    String headerFlag = responseHeaders.get(“MyHeaderFlag”);
}
```

}