# Disable chunked transfer-encoding for JAX-WS Client in WebSphere Application Server 9

Tags: java, websphere, content-length, chunking

I'm trying to disable chunked for a Web Service call I am making from an application hosted in Websphere 9, with the aim of using content length in place of chunking as the Web Service I'm consuming doesn't support chunking.

I have a SOAPHandler class which impliments SOAPHandler giving me access to the handleMessage method. I thought (and everything I've read seems to confirm) that this should be a simple case of then adding the code

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {    
    context.put(HTTPConstants.CHUNKED, "false");
    return true;
}
```

If I step through the code it applies that setting however the client returns a 411 error as it is expecting length in the message which I thought that above should add when disabling the chunked encoding.

If the message is under 32kb it sends no problem and doesn't seem to care length isn't included it's when it's above this size that is seems to be chunking it.

Thanks all.

Comment: You might try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728090/how-to-add-or-manipulate-http-header-in-a-webservice-call-in-java .
I think the header you want is "Transfer-Encoding: identity"

Comment: Thanks Bruce.

I have added code to set this header

    Map<String, Object> requestHeaders = new HashMap<>();
    requestHeaders.put("Transfer-Encoding", "identity"); 
  
 context.put(com.ibm.websphere.webservices.Constants.REQUEST_TRANSPORT_PROPERTIES, requestHeaders);

Unfortunately I still get the same error though. Thank you for the suggestion all the same.

Comment: I tried to format that as code, sorry.

Comment: It looks like you might be able to do it with policy sets (policy sets get "attached" to web services in WebSphere.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/twbs_wsspspthttp.html

Comment: Hi, sorry it's been a while. This actually turned out to be an issue with the end point not the client. Thank you for all your suggestions though.